# Create score based on word occurrences

Tags: r, regex

I have two data frames with columns of words and associated scores for these words. I want to run comments through these frames and create an additive score based on if the words appear in the sentences.

I want to do this across many, many comments so it needs to be computationally efficient. So for example, the sentence "hi, he said. why is it okay" will get a score of .98 + .1 + .2 because the words "hi", "why", and "okay" are in data frame a. Any sentence could potentially have words from several data frames as well.

Can anyone help me create the column "add_score" with a procedure that scales well to large data frames? Thank you

```
a <- data.frame(words = c("hi","no","okay","why"),score = c(.98,.5,.2,.1))
b <- data.frame(words = c("bye","yes","here",score = c(.5,.3,.2)))
comment_df = data.frame(id = c("1","2","3"),  comments = c("hi, he said. why 
is it okay","okay okay okay no","yes, here is it"))
comment_df$add_score = c(1.28,1.1,.5)
```

Comment: you data frame structures are weird. Is that how they really are?

Comment: Your biggest challenge is that you will need to ignore all punctuation. Take a look at the text-mining package `tm`.

Comment: @Stephen Please see my answer. Notice that the data frame `b` you provided as an example will only contain one column. I assume the structure of `b` should be identical as `a` and correct the data frame `b` having two columns in my answer. Let me know if this is not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses functions from `tidyverse` and `stringr`.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

# Merge a and b to create score_df
score_df <- bind_rows(a, b)

# Create a function to calculate score for one string
string_cal <- function(string, score_df){

  temp <- score_df %>%
    # Count the number of words in one string
    mutate(Number = str_count(string, pattern = fixed(words))) %>%
    # Calcualte the score
    mutate(Total_Score = score * Number) 

  # Return the sum
  return(sum(temp$Total_Score))
}

# Use map_dbl to apply the string_cal function over comments
# The results are stored in the add_score column
comment_df <- comment_df %>%
  mutate(add_score = map_dbl(comments, string_cal, score_df = score_df))
```

#### Data Preparation

```
a <- data.frame(words = c("hi","no","okay","why"),
                score = c(.98,.5,.2,.1))
b <- data.frame(words = c("bye","yes","here"),
                score = c(.5,.3,.2))
comment_df <- data.frame(id = c("1","2","3"),
                         comments = c("hi, he said. why is it okay",
                                      "okay okay okay no",
                                      "yes, here is it"))
```

Comment: Cool answer. I guess `fixed(words)` ignores strings that do no start with ['a'...'z'].

Comment: @ChiPak `fixed` is one of the four engines from `stringr` to describe the string pattern. Please see this vignettes to learn more: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html